# Write IRC log to a file, with a file per day

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a bot, and I want it to save the logs in a file. And I want to write each day's log in a different file. I tried that:

```
var date = new Date();
var mes = date.getMonth();
var dia = date.getDate();
var ano = date.getFullYear();
date = dia + "-" + mes + "-" + ano;
var IRClog = fs.createWriteStream('LOG[' + date + '].txt', {
    'flags': 'a'
});
```

How do I check if a day has passed, so I can change the date variable and write to a different file?

Edit:
The ENOENT error was because of "/"s, I changed it to "-"s.

Comment: I don't think you can have `/` in a file name.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Fixed it.

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: No errors. I just don't know how to write a new file in another day without having to restart the script everyday.

Comment: Why not use Log4JS or equivalent and let it do the file rotation work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution might be to keep the date of the last message. If the next message's day is different than the last one, close the file stream and create a new one for the current day.

Another solution might be to use fs.appendFile() for every message, but that's less efficient.